# unity project with simulator sdk checked can not run in xcode,reported "a build only xxx" error.unity 22.3.17 and xcode 15.2

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, simulator

I'm a fresh user for xcode,and this my first time to try to public my unity game to ios.
I make a empty unity project, set the simulator sdk option true in unity, export the project to xcode,but I can't run the game because xcode report "A build only device cannot be used to run this target." every time.I have no idea to solve it after I search so many key worlds in web.I can write a hello world app working well in simulator,but I don't known how to make unity project in xcode work. I need help,any one can tell me why this happend and how to solve?
unity 22.3.17 and xcode 15.2.Simulator is running,iPhone15 pro max - iOS 17.2.Macbook Air(M1),14.1.1.

Here is some screen shot(may be useful?)
[unity build setting shotcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7taI.png)

[xcode error report and options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s9jA.png)

[another xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr5EH.png)

[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt2P9.jpg)

Very Thanks!‍♂️

1.download unity 22.3.17 and install with ios exporter.

2.creat a 2d template project.

3.make simulator sdk option selected in Unity buildsetting.

4.export the xcode project

5.open xxx.xcodeprj

6.click run button

7.see the error

I keep simulator running while I do the steps.The vitual machine is iPhone15 pro max - iOS 17.2.

Comment: I believe you need to select a specific emulated target instead of "any". What does Manage Run Destinations show you?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Do you mean [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr5EH.png) ?

Comment: No, I mean the option shown at the bottom of the 3rd screenshot. This may also help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/xcode-14-3-simulator-not-launch-when-build-unity-2021-3-22f1-macbook-m1.1423326/

Comment: @RetiredNinja Its helpfu.I should go to try

Comment: @RetiredNinja I changed the Xcode > Product > Destination > Destination architectures option following the tips from your link,it work!I have a little problem,where is the option defined in the project?Can I change this option by texteditor without xcode?

Comment: I don't have a Mac here so I can't poke at it. I would assume it would be in the xcproject file and once you know what the option is you could edit it manually or with a post-build task in Unity.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is another topic,I will keep my notice on it.Can you post your comment as answer so I can finish this question?Very thanks✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the Xcode > Product > Destination > Destination architectures >both,then all things ok.
UnityProject is x86 and xcode not show arm simulator default.